# Remove tags from m3u file

Tags: linux, bash, m3u

I have m3u list provided like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 1" tvg-name="Channel 1" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo1.png" timeshift="5" catchup="default" catchup-source="http://1.1.1.1/325/mono-{utc}-{lutc}.m3u8?token=secret" group-title="Group" ,13 Channel 1
http://2.2.2.2/325/video.m3u8?token=secret
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 2" tvg-name="Channel 2" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo2.png" timeshift="5" catchup="default" catchup-source="http://1.1.1.1/324/mono-{utc}-{lutc}.m3u8?token=secret" group-title="Group" ,Channel 2
http://2.2.2.2/324/video.m3u8?token=secret
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 3" tvg-name="Channel 3" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo3.png" timeshift="5" catchup="default" catchup-source="http://1.1.1.1/323/mono-{utc}-{lutc}.m3u8?token=secret" group-title="Group" ,Channel 3
http://2.2.2.2/323/video.m3u8?token=secret
```

I want to change catchup type to fs and remove all catchup-source tags, so result should be:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 1" tvg-name="Channel 1" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo1.png" timeshift="5" catchup="fs" group-title="Group" ,13 Channel 1
http://2.2.2.2/325/video.m3u8?token=secret
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 2" tvg-name="Channel 2" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo2.png" timeshift="5" catchup="fs" group-title="Group" ,Channel 2
http://2.2.2.2/324/video.m3u8?token=secret
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="Channel 3" tvg-name="Channel 3" tvg-logo="http://host/logo/logo3.png" timeshift="5" catchup="fs" group-title="Group" ,Channel 3
http://2.2.2.2/323/video.m3u8?token=secret
```

How to do that in bash? I tried with sed, but without success, can you point me right direction?

To remove any specific substring, I can use sed like this:

```
sed '/text to remove/d' ./file
```

In my case, string to remove is vary, between `catchup="default"` and `group-title=` and get result as I posted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you tried :)

Comment: Actually, I know how to remove specific substrings with sed, but I have no idea how to remove various substrings between 2 words, so my case it's more complicated

Comment: That's okay! If our code worked perfectly, we wouldn't be here :)

Comment: I edited question. Unfotunately, I have no idea how to get what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
shopt -s extglob ; cat file.txt | while read -r line ; do mapfile -t -d ' ' Line < <(printf '%s' "${line}" | cut -f 1-99 -d ' ') ; for field in "${Line[@]}"; do if [[ "$field" =~ catchup-source=.* ]]; then : ; elif [[ "$field" == catchup=\"default\" ]]; then printf '%s ' 'catchup="fs"'; else [[ -n "$field" ]] && { if [[ "$field" =~ .*$'\n'.* ]]; then printf '%s' "$field" ; else printf '%s ' "$field" ; fi } ; fi; done ; done
```

Explanation:

Read the file line by line, split it into fields with space as delimiter and store those in an array. For each field in the array check the contents: if the content is catchup default thing, change it to catchup=fs thing, if content is catchup-source, just continue (':' meaning true), else check if the field has content (-n), and if it has content, check if the content of the field has a newline and if it does just print the content, else print the content with the space which was the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You were halfway there.

```
sed -i.bak  -E -e 's/catchup="default" /catchup="fs" /g;s/catchup-source=[^ ]+ //g' file
```

Using search and replace for partial strings `s/MATCH/REPLACEMENT/` is what you needed (rather than deleting the matching line `/MATCH/d`).

So we search for every literal occurrence of `catchup="default"`  and replace it with nothing `//g` (the `g` is technically not necessary as there should be only one occurrence of `catchup=`) `s/catchup="default" //g` and then do the same for `catchup-source=[^ ]+`  (`catchup-source=` followed by anything that's not a space followed by a space `[^ ]+` . Done.

We do this as an infile-replacement `-i` and tell it to create a backup-version `-i.bak`.

Comment: It removes `catchup="default"`, but it should be renamed to `catchup="fs"`

Comment: Oops.  Easy fix.